# Rewrite Nginx dont work

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

http://web.xxxxxx.com/inmuebles-en-venta-en-miraflores-distrito-en-lima-provincia-en-lima-departamento-con-2-banos-con-3-dormitorios-de-18-a-340-metros-cuadrados-de-21-a-5351-dolares.html

the url return this:
preciomax = venta0 and I do not know why

wlistado?tab=venta&distrito=miraflores&provincia=lima&departamento=lima&txt_banos=2&txt_dormi=3&areamin=18&areamax=340&preciomin=21&preciomax=**venta0**

this is my rewrite; but the last parameter dont work
rewrite '^/inmuebles-en-(venta|alquiler)-en-(.*)-distrito-en-(.*)-provincia-en-(.*)-departamento-con-([0-6]+)-banos?-con-([0-6]+)-dormitorios?-de-([0-9]+)-a-([0-9]+)-metros-cuadrados-de-([0-9]+)-a-([0-9]+)-dolares.html$' /nuestros-inmuebles.php?operacion=$1&distrito=$2&provincia=$3&departamento=$4&banos=$5&dormi=$6&areai=$7&areaf=$8&precioi=$9&preciofin=$10 break;

help please

Comment: Try this `${10}`

Comment: i try your solution but nginx show error:

Comment: [root@CentOS-75-64-minimal ~]# nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown "10" variable
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Well, looks like there cannot be more than 10 positional match groups. But you could try named group match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading a litle:

RewriteRule backreferences: These are backreferences of the form $N (0 <= N <= 9). $1 to $9 provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions. $0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.

and following your suggestion the syntax would remain:

rewrite '^/inmuebles-en-(?venta|alquiler)-en-(?.*)-distrito-en-(?.*)-provincia-en-(?.*)-departamento-con-(?[0-6])-banos?-con-(?[0-6])-dormitorios?-de-(?[0-9]+)-a-(?[0-9]+)-metros-cuadrados-de-(?[0-9]+)-a-(?[0-9]+)-dolares.html$' /nuestros-inmuebles.php?operacion=${group1}&distrito=${group2}&provincia=${group3}&departamento=${group4}&banos=${group5}&dormi=${group6}&areai=${group7}&areaf=${group8}&precioi=${group9}&preciof=${group10} break;

thanks a lot Alexey Ten